# Как, в JavaScript, получить переменную из другого скрипта

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(
                function()
                {
                    var myParam = "someText";
                }
            );
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>  
        <script type="text/javascript">
//Как получить здесь значение переменной myParam
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это можно сделать, например, через глобальную переменную:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(
            function()
            {
                var myParam = "someText";
                window.myParam = myParam;
            }
        );
    </script>
</head>
<body>  
    <script type="text/javascript">
       alert(window.myParam);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

или так - объявление переменной вынесено наружу в общую область видимости:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var myParam;
        $(
            function()
            {
                myParam = "someText";
            }
        );
    </script>
</head>
<body>  
    <script type="text/javascript">
       alert(myParam);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

Есть такое интересное решение с использование глобальной переменной `$` Jquery:

```html
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">   </script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function() {
              $.myParam = "someText";
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>  
        <script type="text/javascript">
          $(function() {
            alert( $.myParam );
          });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Для этого и есть глобальные переменные. Правило: область видимости переменных.

### Правило:

Глобальные переменные: создаются вне функций, циклов, условий `if(){} else{}` и блоков кода. Могут вызываться везде и постоянно.

Локальные переменные: создаются внутри функций, циклов, условий и блоках кода. Могут вызываться только в них (т.е ты не можешь вызвать локальную переменную вне её функции или что у тебя там).

```js
var globalScope = "Меня ты можешь использовать где угодно";

function f() {
 var localScope = "А мння только при вызове функции.";
 alert(localScope);
}

alert(globalScope);
document.write(globalScope);
f();
```

**НО**: кто тебе мешает сделать так:

```html
<script>
var aaa = "some text";

function main(){
var object = document.getElementById("asl");
 object.onmouseover = function(){
  aaa = "tes";
 };
}
window.onload = main;
</script>
<b id="asl">Что-то</b>

<span class="i">Вывод: </span>

<script>
document.getElementsByClassName("i")[0].onmouseover = function(){
 this.innerHTML = "<i>" + aaa + "</i>";
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

jQuery - зло :) Вариант решения не через jQuery.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
                function FuncName () {
                    var myParam = "someText";
                    return myParam;
                }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>  
        <script type="text/javascript">
            alert(FuncName ());
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Единственное что, я получил значение переменной, к самой переменной доступа нет.
Ответ рядом, демонстрирует получения глобальной переменной через window.

Comment: Всегда пользовался и буду пользоваться JQuery :D А так +1

Comment: @Yuri ну и зря)

Comment: Чем Jquery не угодил?

Comment: @Yuri Почитай эту статью на [lurkmore](https://lurkmore.to/JavaScript#jQuery). Все поймешь :D

Comment: @EugenEray, Боже, я прочитал первые две строки и закрыл. Этому "писаке" следовало бы сначала научиться писать нормально

Comment: @Yuri  Не спорю. Но на то он и рофл.

Comment: @EugenEray, в CSS разбираешься?

Comment: @Yuri  Поохо, не умею создавать сложные фигуры, когда получается огромная колбаса кода.